# Initial, Default and User defined Keys

Tags: l3keys

I would like to pass user-defined keys.  But when the user does not specify values, the default values are used.  I need some explanation on what to do in the `\setdimensions` command.  What does `.initial` work out exactly ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Define dimension variables
\dim_new:N \l_mymodule_width_dim
\dim_new:N \l_mymodule_height_dim
\dim_new:N \l_mymodule_margin_dim

% Define a new key-value family
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
  {
    width  .dim_set:N = \l_mymodule_width_dim,
    width .initial:n = 34pt,
    width .default:n = 34pt,

    height .dim_set:N = \l_mymodule_height_dim,
    height .initial:n = 34pt,
    height .default:n = 34pt,

    margin .dim_set:N = \l_mymodule_margin_dim,
    margin .initial:n = 34pt,
    margin .default:n = 34pt,
  }

% Command to use the keys
\NewDocumentCommand{\setdimensions}{o}
  {
    % Use the dimensions in your document or perform other actions
    \fbox
    {
      Width:  \dim_use:N \l_mymodule_width_dim \\
      Height: \dim_use:N \l_mymodule_height_dim \\
      Margin: \dim_use:N \l_mymodule_margin_dim
    }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% Example usage
\setdimensions{
  width = 8cm,
  height = 4cm,
  margin = 1.5cm,
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: default is the value you would get from `\setdimensions{width}` . I have some doubts that it makes much sense here.

Comment: It would be interesting for me to see a version that takes advantage of all the possibilities of using the keys.

Comment: this is all documented, `initial` sets thevalue at the point you use `\keys_define:nn`  and `default` is the value used  if you use the key with no `=value`.

Comment: it's not clear what your examle is supposed to be showing, you do not use the keys anywhere, just typeset the input list

Comment: also you have declared your command with a single optional argument so `{
  width = 8cm,
  height = 4cm,
  margin = 1.5cm,
}` is not an argument to the command, it is simply text typeset after the command has finished.

Comment: I want to set the values for the variables using the contents of the keys when calling the command.

Comment: @Ragonese that's what I show in my answer, your code declares some keys but never sets them to any values (other than the initial values you set at declaration)

Comment: I want to figure out how to set the variables using the capabilities of the key-value system for the command.  I have to call `\keys_set:nn` but was wondering how that should be used.

Comment: as I showed in my answer, but first you need to learn the basics of defining commands in latex, just putting some key=value in a text stream does not magically make them an argument of a command, you need to define the command to take an argument and use that argument `#1` to do whatever you want (set keys in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd rather make the argument optional, so you can just say `\setdimensions` to use the `initial` values, you can do that provided you write `\setdimensions[<list of key-values>]` with square rather than curly brackets.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Define a new key-value family
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
{
  width  .dim_set:N = \l_mymodule_width_dim,
  width .initial:n = 34pt,
  width .default:n = 10pt,
  
  height .dim_set:N = \l_mymodule_height_dim,
  height .initial:n = 34pt,
  height .default:n = 10pt,
  
  margin .dim_set:N = \l_mymodule_margin_dim,
  margin .initial:n = 34pt,
  margin .default:n = 10pt,
}

% Command to use the keys
\NewDocumentCommand{\setdimensions} { O{} }
{
  % Use the dimensions in your document or perform other actions
  \fbox
  {
    \keys_set:nn { mymodule } { #1 }
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      Width: & \dim_use:N \l_mymodule_width_dim \\
      Height: & \dim_use:N \l_mymodule_height_dim \\
      Margin: & \dim_use:N \l_mymodule_margin_dim
    \end{tabular}
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% Example usage
With custom values:

\setdimensions[%
  width = 8cm,
  height = 4cm,
  margin = 1.5cm,
]

With initial values:

\setdimensions

With default values:

\setdimensions[width,height,margin]

\end{document}
```

produces

[image: custom, initial and default values]

Whether this is the kind of example using the different values you wanted, I'm not sure ....

Comment: What would be the reason for choosing `O{}` over `o` ?

Comment: @Ragonese You could use `o`. Then you'd need to test `\IfValueTF {#1} {\keys_set:nn {mymodule} {#1}}{\keys_set:nn {mymodule} {}}`. It would be different if you weren't using `initial` values because then you could just skip setting the keys if the option wasn't used. But you want the initials, so it seemed easier to just pass a default empty value.

Comment: Then if it is empty, initial gets applied. And If I do not use initial I would only do `\IfValueT {#1} {\keys_set:nn {mymodule} {#1}} `. Correct ?

Comment: @Ragonese If you don't use `initial` and you use `o` in place of `O{}`, then, yes, use the `\IfValue...` stuff. But you will want to make sure you have fallback values defined somehow. But you could just do `\dim_set:Nn \l_mymodule_width_dim {20pt}` or whatever in the preamble for that.

Comment: When not setting initial values, the call to `\setdimensions` uses values of `0.0pt`.  Would this how things should be, using values of `0.0pt` for dimensions when not setting tho key values ?

Comment: @Ragonese If you don't set initial values and don't use `\dim_set:Nn ...` to initialise them then, yes, they'll be 0.

Comment: @Ragonese beware, there is a misconception. If the argument is empty the current values in your variables will be used, not necessarily the `.initial:n` once. `.initial:n` only sets the values once at point of use, it doesn't add any hooks or whatnot to magically reset those values later. So in fact `O{}` with `\keys_set:nn {mymodule} {#1}` and `o` with `\IfValueT {#1} { \keys_set:nn {mymodule} {#1}` are equivalent, they both do nothing if you omit the optional argument.

Comment: @Skillmon But in this case, the values are being set within a local group. It is true that if you change them at the top level, those values will override the initial ones. But you're right that I forgot the initial values get set when you define them, as opposed to when they are used. So it makes no odds which form of `o`/`O`, as you say. But the current values will always be the initial ones if you only set them using `\mydimensions` or another macro which sets them only locally.

Comment: @cfr absolutely correct. I just wanted to make sure OP knows the difference; my comment was regarding "Then if it is empty, initial gets applied", which is wrong or at least misleadingly formulated. Even if OP knew the difference it could confuse future visitors.

Comment: @Skillmon Agreed. And I was definitely contributing to that confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not really clear enough to answer, but I'll try...

The code produces

[image]

The text in a box has no space as it is set up in `\ExplSyntaxOn` and it just shows the values of the three registers which are set by the `initial` key as those values are set when the keys are defined, and you never set any keys after that.

The command is defined to have one optional argument which it never uses, so the argument would be used inside `[...]`  so the following tokens

```
{
  width = 8cm,
  height = 4cm,
  margin = 1.5cm,
}
```

are not seen by the command at all, and are just typeset as text, as shown in the above image.

---

I would guess you intended

[image]

Where the command is defined to take an argument which is used to set the key values. The key settings are contained in a local group so will not be changed after the command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Define dimension variables
\dim_new:N \l_mymodule_width_dim
\dim_new:N \l_mymodule_height_dim
\dim_new:N \l_mymodule_margin_dim

% Define a new key-value family
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
  {
    width  .dim_set:N = \l_mymodule_width_dim,
    width .initial:n = 34pt,
    width .default:n = 34pt,

    height .dim_set:N = \l_mymodule_height_dim,
    height .initial:n = 34pt,
    height .default:n = 34pt,

    margin .dim_set:N = \l_mymodule_margin_dim,
    margin .initial:n = 34pt,
    margin .default:n = 34pt,
  }

% Command to use the keys
\NewDocumentCommand{\setdimensions}{m}
{
 \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn{mymodule}{#1}
    % Use the dimensions in your document or perform other actions
    \fbox
    {\begin{tabular}{l}
      Width:  \dim_use:N \l_mymodule_width_dim \\
      Height: \dim_use:N \l_mymodule_height_dim \\
       Margin: \dim_use:N \l_mymodule_margin_dim
      \end{tabular}
    }
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% Example usage
\setdimensions{
  width = 8cm,
  height = 4cm,
  margin = 1.5cm,
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does just having `\keys_set:nn{mymodule}{#1}` allow all the capabilities of using the keys through calling the command ?

Comment: @Ragonese  I have no idea what you mean sorry, `\keys_set:nn` is how you use keys, you had not used the keys at all.

Comment: I want to call the command with all the possibilities provided by the keys.  Meaning 1) with user-defined values, 2) with default values, 3) with initial values,

Comment: @Ragonese that is what this does. What is your question?

Comment: How would I call `\setdimensions{` to use the initial values in keys ?

Comment: `\setdimensions{}` of course. If you have not changed the values you get the initial value, it's just the natural meaning of initial value.

Comment: Why do you group the code exactly, using `{{` and `}}`, rather than just `{` and `}` only ?

Comment: @Ragonese the outer braces are not a group, they delimit the argument of the definition.

Comment: I am referring to `{{` just before `\keys_set:nn{mymodule}{#1}`.

Comment: @Ragonese yes exactly: the first `{` is delimiting the argument of `\NewDocumentCommand`  the second starts a scoping group to keep the key setting local. In his version egreg moved the settings inside the fbox so they are already local to that box but if you removed the fbox you would need to add a group somewhere as I show here.

Comment: @Ragonese  compare `\def\foo{ \bfseries abc}  \foo xyz`  and  `\def\foo{{ \bfseries abc}}  \foo xyz`   in the first xyz is bold as the font change is not in a group, in the second xyz is not bold.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle please use `\group_begin:...\group_end:` for code-level groups instead of `{...}` in L3 as per convention.

Comment: @Skillmon yes I guess that would make the distinction clearer, I'll update

Answer (score 0):

This answer just aims to clear up a few details, not provide some code you can run.

Since the key-defining and key-setting is separated in `l3keys` you'd have to run a separate `\keys_set:nn` to set a first/initial value. Since this is cumbersome and separates the key declaration from its initialisation, the `.initial:n` handler was added.

All that handler does is set a key to a value (so in essence `<key> .initial:n = { <value> }` inside of `\keys_define:nn { <module> }` is the same as if you'd put a `\keys_set:nn { <module> } { <key> = { <value> } }` at that point, it doesn't add anything else to the key code. So any later setting of that key (outside of a nested group) will overwrite that `.initial:n` value, and it's impossible to get it back if it hasn't been manually recorded through different means.